# Filebeat holds the log file even after it has finished reading

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have a scenario where i have to move the logs files to another folder using a tool robocopy.
While doing this, it throws an error saying Permission denied.

Using resourcemonitor i have verified that Filebeat holds the logfile even after it has reached EOF.
Due to this reason, i'm unable to move the logs.

As a temporary workaround, i have disabled the elastic search then it works fine without any issues.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Do you keep writing in to the same log file Or once filebeat reach EOF you done writing to it?

Comment: No i don't write anything into it once it reaches EOF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `close_eof` option in your FileBeat config YML.

For example (you didn't share your config) like that:

```
paths:
    - C:\logs\*
  input_type: log
  document_type: A 
  close_eof: true
```